# How to build the same target twice with different preprocessor macro set?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

We have an XCode project for a plug-in to an application built for MacOS only.

We would like to build the same sources twice - once for a full version and once for a trial version. The only difference is a preprocessor macro (like TRIAL=1 for the trial version and nothing for the full version).

The build product is supposed to be saved/archived into a something like ~/Build/Trial|Full/myName.appPlugIn.

One of the version is supposed to be copied to the app-specific folder for debugging purposes. I would like to choose which one as needed.

Currently I have two xconfig files - Full.xconfig and Trial.xconfig which sets the preprocessor macro as needed and sets TRIAL_OR_FULL = Full or Trial value respectively.

How do you suggest to set the targets/schemes/*.xconfigs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:
1) Click on the project in the inspector
2) Right-Click on the app target and select Duplicate / renamed it to have Trial in the name
3) Add a TRIAL=1 preprocessor macro in Build Settings for the trial
4) Edit Scheme and Duplicate the main scheme
5) Click on Build for the scheme. 
6) Add the new trial target and removed the old one.
7) Pick the new scheme and build.